# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user' Django admin

Tags: python, django, admin, panel, wsgi

When I trying to access the admin page it gives me the following error:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 21, 2016 - 15:26:14
Django version 1.9.7, using settings 'librato_chart_sender_web.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /admin/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 265, in wrapper
    return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 233, in inner
    if not self.has_permission(request):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 173, in has_permission
    return request.user.is_active and request.user.is_staff
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
[21/Jun/2016 15:26:18] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78473
```

Im quite new in django ... but I followed this tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/

I dont have any custom AdminSites and custom AdminModels.

I already googled about this problem but still I cannot solve it for my case in any way. Can you help ?

here is my `settings.py`:

```
"""
Django settings for librato_chart_sender_web project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.dev20160523235928.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*1@+=wzrqx^6$9z&@2@d8r(w$js+ktw45lv2skez(=kz+rwff_'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'librato_chart_sender',
    'fontawesome',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'librato_chart_sender_web.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'librato_chart_sender/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'librato_chart_sender_web.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'GMT'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    ('css', 'librato_chart_sender/static/css'),
    ('js', 'librato_chart_sender/static/js'),
    ('fonts', 'librato_chart_sender/static/fonts'),
]
```

and `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Configuration

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Configuration)
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

To resolve this go to `settings.py` where there is new-style `MIDDLEWARE` (introduced in Django 1.10)

Change that to old-style `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware

Comment: If using Django 1.10 and virtualenv, make sure the virtual machine is running before starting `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: @asgaines If you're running django 1.10 you don't need to do this, MIDDLEWARE is a 1.10+ setting. Also virtualenv is not a virtual machine.

Comment: This seems like the same as @GonçaloCorreia's answer (which is older), but with less detail...

Comment: This method is deprecated. This error occurs when your the ordering of your middleware classes is not properly ordered. However, the best way to resolve this is by setting your 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' as the first of the middlewares before the  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', and the others follow.

Comment: For future readers, the only two you need to fix `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'` are `SessionMiddleware` and `AuthenticationMiddleware`.

Comment: @OrangeDog I'm running 1.10, project was also created in 1.10. And my SessionMiddleware is before AuthenticationMiddleware. And I'm still seeing this error.

Comment: Django says "All middleware classes included with Django are compatible with both settings.". Why do we have to use the old-style `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` then?

Answer (score 72):

I found the answer. The variable name on:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

`MIDDLEWARE` is the new-style configuration introduced in Django 1.10. Change the name to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and now it works.

So now the code is:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. As an aside, you might want to generate a new secret key for your project as you've posted your current one in a public domain (not good!)

Comment: MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES was changed to MIDDLEWARE in 1.10. ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/ ) If you are using previous versions(<=1.9), use MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

Comment: This happened to me due to having to downgrade from a previous 1.10 install to 1.9.

Comment: If using Django 1.10 and virtualenv, make sure the virtual machine is running before starting `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: This is not correct. I have both, and still get this error. Even if I completely remove MIDDLEWARE, I still get the error.

Comment: @Cerin you should not remove MIDDLEWARE, if you have version 1.10 you remove _CLASSES and leave only MIDDLEWARE.

If you have version 1.9 you have to have MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

Comment: @margincall I've edited the answer to make it clearer that `MIDDLEWARE` is the new-style way of doing things.

Answer (score 42):

In case anyone is having this problem with Django 2.0, the following configuration with new-style `MIDDLEWARE` seems to work ([docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware)):

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: The other answers make it sound like Django deprecated `MIDDLEWARE` and changed to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` at some point, but that's misleading. `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` has always been the old way of doing it, and `MIDDLEWARE` has always been the new-style. I've edited the other answers to make this clearer, as well as this answer.

Comment: Just with other words: remove SessionAuthenticationMiddleware in dj2.0

Comment: All these suggestions of changing the MIDDLEWARE text is not working for me. I have a new 2.0.4 installation, running locally only in Debug mode. It was working fine for a week, then today decided to deny me access to POST variables. No amount of playing with MIDDLEWARE is fixing it.

Comment: @mirek Why should I `remove SessionAuthenticationMiddleware`?

Comment: @Timo, no. The recommended solutions didn't work for me. I had to create a whole new Django project from scratch and copy over my files.

Answer (score 26):

In case anyone is having the same problem in django 2.0.2 or later,

just update

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

with

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

It worked for me cause i created my project with
django 1.0.x but later updated to django 2.0.2

Comment: Finally, only this worked for me: using MIDDLEWARE and no     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware'.

Comment: This was the proper solution for me upgrading from Django 1.11 to 2.1: (1) change 'MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES' tuple to 'MIDDLEWARE' list (2) Remove 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware'

Answer (score 16):

You should not change MIDDLEWARE to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. What happens here is more likely that you created the app with django 1.10 and now you are running it with 1.9 or a previous version.

Make sure you use a specific version of django(and all other libraries) so your project doesn't break when deploying or running on different machines.

If you have a stable codebase simply run:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

And then when deploying or setting up a new env just do:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You should always consider using fixed versions of your libraries(and hopefully virtual envs), and when upgrading dependencies test each version change.

Comment: I think this is the best answer; don't downgrade to older features like the other answers say, unless you have to.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error in my production server and thanks to sentry's breadcrumbs I saw that the error that was raising had to do with my settings, especially the ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Django version 1.10.8 with python 2.7.

My previous settings:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0',
                 'beta.mydomain.co.uk',
                 'mydomain.co.uk',
                 'www.mydomain.co.uk',
                 'alpha.mydomain.co.uk']
```

Sentry Breadcrumbs screen shot:
[image: sentry breadcrumb screenshot]

After that I looked around and found this:

> *A value beginning with a period can be used as a subdomain wildcard:
>   '.example.com' will match example.com, www.example.com, and any other
>   subdomain of example.com.*

Link to [Django official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)

So my final settings that solved my problem:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0',
                 'mydomain.co.uk',
                 'www.mydomain.co.uk',
                 '.mydomain.co.uk']
```

Hope this was useful :)

Answer (score 2):

My solution was that my Django ver. was 1.9 I reinstalled back to 1.10 without changing MIDDLEWARE to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.