# django-user-accounts 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django

So im following the documentation for **django-user-accounts** 
Im getting an error message **'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'** The documentation asked to put in this code

```
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
...
"account.middleware.LocaleMiddleware",
"account.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware",
...
   ]
```

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES is deprecated, so i put the two lines of code in just MIDDLEWARE.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'account',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 ]

MIDDLEWARE = [
"account.middleware.LocaleMiddleware",
"account.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware",
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 ]
```

root urls.py

```
  from django.conf.urls import url, include
  from django.contrib import admin

  urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r"^account/", include("account.urls")),
   ]
```

I ran **makemigrations** for **accounts** , and i ran **migrate**. The server ran just fine with no errors , but whenever i go to **localhost:8000/accounts/login** i either get a **404** or **no attribute 'user'**

Comment: What Django version are you using? Also, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949198/wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-user-django-admin

Comment: im using django 1.10.5 , ive looked at other questions and none of the answers helped

Comment: actually thanks that link is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this while using Django 2.0 was to make sure that Django's Middleware came before django-user-accounts Middleware, and I would assume that is the case with all apps.

Simply changing the order around to this worked for me:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    "account.middleware.LocaleMiddleware",
    "account.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware",
]
```