# Django auth views causing Http502 (with Gunicorn + Nginx)

Tags: django, gunicorn

I'm getting 502s when I try to access any of the views that rely on `auth` (so `/admin/login/`, posting to my own `/login/` page, etc). *It's not occurring on any other views/requests.*

Here's the nginx acess log:

```
GET /admin/login/ HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0
```

Not much that's going to help me there. Here's an extract from the gunicorn log (the first line is a worker booting from when the last one died):

```
[2018-01-15 19:44:43 +0000] [4775] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4775
[2018-01-15 19:46:10 +0000] [4679] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:4775)
[2018-01-15 19:46:10 +0000] [4775] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4775)
```

What's causing me to lose workers and get 502s?

Edit: I'm using django 2.0.1, django-axes 4.0.1. I'm pretty sure this is an axes issue, but I don't know how to diagnose it.

Comment: Is this happening when requesting on localhost? or is this a remote ip request?

Comment: Try enabling [DEBUG logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/#examples) to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kichik I enabled debug logging, and discovered that the views were throwing a `"WSGIRequest has no attribute 'user'"` exception due to me using middleware settings in pre-django2 format. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47795057) solved the issue.