# i have two projects in django i can not open admin site for my second project,but i can open for my first project,can any one help me

Tags: django

AttributeError at /admin/
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 2.0.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
Exception Location: C:\Users\vaaz\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py in has_permission, line 186
Python Executable:  C:\Users\vaaz\Desktop\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:
['C:\Users\vaaz\website1',
 'C:\Windows\system32\python34.zip',
 'C:\Users\vaaz\Desktop\venv\DLLs',
 'C:\Users\vaaz\Desktop\venv\lib',
 'C:\Users\vaaz\Desktop\venv\Scripts',
 'C:\Python34\Lib',
 'C:\Python34\DLLs',
 'C:\Users\vaaz\Desktop\venv',
 'C:\Users\vaaz\Desktop\venv\lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 12 Mar 2018 10:21:49 +0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949198/wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-user-django-admin)

with your limited error description I can only suggest a few things that were mentioned in the above post:

1. Older Django versions use `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (...)` in the **settings.py** rather than `MIDDLEWARE = (...)` try changing that variable.
2. If you are using virtualenv be sure to activate it before trying to runserver
3. If you created your app in a different version of Django and then installed it on another version it might give you errors.