# python- Django local server refuses to connect to admin page

Tags: python, django

I am running Django 2.0 and everything is set up correctly. When I try to run the local Django server it runs fine. but when I try to access the admin page it shows the error below. I have looked for other solutions online but none of them seem to fix my problem. Can anyone help?

```
AttributeError at /admin/
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 2.0.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py in has_permission, line 186
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['/Users/zeinalabidin/Desktop/website',
    '/Users/zeinalabidin/Desktop/website',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 15 Mar 2018 03:13:25 +0000
```

`settings.py`:

```py
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'ls6+rdv27yn8k9&g7s5o%egm_jxc-^ni7n--n^xbwr7u1i%hw-'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'music.apps.MusicConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

`wsgi.py`:

```py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "website.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: whats your django version ?

Comment: Can you share your settings file code?

Comment: "everything is setup correctly" - well...

Comment: migration done ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user' Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949198/wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-user-django-admin)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a settings file from an old version of Django. Change MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES to just MIDDLEWARE.

Answer (score 0):

Change MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES to MIDDLEWARE and Perform your migrations. It should work.